# Unable to create Podman network due to no free subnet pools

Tags: fedora, podman

I am having trouble creating podman networks on Fedora 38

When I run `podman network create example` I see this error:

```
Error: could not find free subnet from subnet pools
```

My default network is properly created

```
$ podman network ls         
NETWORK ID    NAME        DRIVER
2f259bab93aa  podman      bridge

$ podman network inspect podman
[
     {
          "name": "podman",
          "id": "2f259bab93aaaaa2542ba43ef33eb990d0999ee1b9924b557b7be53c0b7a1bb9",
          "driver": "bridge",
          "network_interface": "podman0",
          "created": "2023-06-24T16:01:44.938116446-06:00",
          "subnets": [
               {
                    "subnet": "10.88.0.0/16",
                    "gateway": "10.88.0.1"
               }
          ],
          "ipv6_enabled": false,
          "internal": false,
          "dns_enabled": false,
          "ipam_options": {
               "driver": "host-local"
          }
     }
]
```

I have tried adding some subnet definitions in the file `/etc/containers/containers.conf` despite things working fine previously without this file in the past

```
default_subnet = "10.88.0.0/16"

default_subnet_pools = [
  {"base" = "10.89.0.0/16", "size" = 24},
  {"base" = "10.90.0.0/15", "size" = 24},
  {"base" = "10.92.0.0/14", "size" = 24},
  {"base" = "10.96.0.0/11", "size" = 24},
  {"base" = "10.128.0.0/9", "size" = 24},
]
```

I hoped this would let me create a podman network, but no luck

Answer (score 1):

Faced pretty similar issue, exact same error message.
Our homenetwork using 10.11.12.0/23 subnet
Checked `ip a`:

```
inet 10.11.12.5/8 brd 10.255.255.255 scope global noprefixroute wlp2s0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 10.11.12.69/22 brd 10.11.15.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0
   valid_lft 24017sec preferred_lft 24017sec
```

Then I've updated `/etc/containers/containers.conf` (probaly i could just fix by updating 10.11.12.5/8, I'm not good at networking)

```
default_subnet_pools = [
  {"base" = "192.168.129.0/24", "size" = 24},
  {"base" = "192.168.130.0/24", "size" = 24},
  {"base" = "192.168.131.0/24", "size" = 24},
  {"base" = "192.168.132.0/24", "size" = 24},
]
```

and now it's all works fine. Hope it helps!